# Prolem in replacing special characters "@" with a blank using regex replace function

Tags: regex, special-characters

i am using following regex expression to replace

```
query=query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9*?:.+-^""_]+/g,'')
```

But when my query is `diam!@#%d` i get `diam@d` after execution of this.
it means it is not replacing `@` . Why is so ??

Comment: what would you like to accomplish? If it is to remove everything except letters, why not use `query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/, '')` directly?

Comment: epoch : i juss want to replace @ with a blank ie with ''

Comment: epoch : No i want to replace characters other than i have given in the expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `-` sign in your regex (`-` => `\-`), i.e.: `[^a-zA-Z 0-9*?:.+\-^""_]+`, therefore it will match: `!@#%`.

Comment: +1 or move it to the start or the end `[^a-zA-Z 0-9*?:.+^""_-]+`

Comment: polishchuk: why so, why Escape sign only affecting @ charecter

Comment: `-` is reserved within character classes

Comment: @Romi, inside `[]` `-` means range of chars, i.e. `[+-^]` means from char `+` to char `^`.